# python : list of dictionary values by alphabetical order of keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary, alphabetical

Is there a simple way of getting a list of values from a dictionary, but in the way that all values are ordered by alphabetical order of keys in dictionary?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have several options; the easiest is to just sort the *items*, picking out the values with a list comprehension:

```
[v for k, v in sorted(dictionary.iteritems())]
```

as tuples are sorted lexicographically; by key first, then on value. Replace `iteritems()` with `items()` if you are using Python 3.

You can sort just the keys and translate those to values:

```
[dictionary[k] for k in sorted(dictionary)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> dictionary = {'foo': 42, 'bar': 38, 'baz': 20}
>>> [v for k, v in sorted(dictionary.iteritems())]
[38, 20, 42]
>>> [dictionary[k] for k in sorted(dictionary)]
[38, 20, 42]
```

Accessing keys afterwards is also the faster option:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('[v for k, v in sorted(dictionary.iteritems())]', 'from __main__ import dictionary')
3.4159910678863525
>>> timeit.timeit('[d[key] for key in sorted(d)]', 'from __main__ import dictionary as d')
1.5645101070404053
```

Yes, that's more than twice as fast to sort a small dictionary a million times.

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous ways to do that. one way is by using `sorted` on the dict:

```
>>> d = {'c': 1, 'b': 2, 'e': 3, 'a': 4}
>>> l = [d[key] for key in sorted(d)]
>>> print(l)
[4, 2, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for that you can use `zip`. Here is an example:

```
y = {'a': 1, 'd':4, 'h':3, 'b': 2}

a = y.keys()
b = y.values()

print [d for (c,d) in sorted(zip(a,b))]
[1, 2, 4, 3]
```

or simply:

```
print [i[1] for i in sorted(y.items())]
```

You can try it out here: http://repl.it/R8e

Comment: No need to even call `.keys()`, and what is wrong with `sorted(y)` to get keys then map to values? Or using `sorted(y.items())`?